# File Upload Using ajax in Struts 1.2

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, struts

Does anyone know how to upload file using ajax in struts 1.2. without jquery

Here is my code,

Javascript

```
function addPhoto(){
var uploadUrl = 'doAjaxWork.do?reqCode=uploadPhoto';
var file = document.getElementById("imageFile").files[0];
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.onload = function (e) {

};xhr.onerror = function (e) {

};
xhr.open("GET", uploadUrl, true);

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.size);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Type", file.type);
xhr.send(file);
alert('end');
return true;
```

}

Java script function is working fine. What I am not able to figure out is how to get the file from java backend. I could not find any examples from the internet either.

**Java**

```
  DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
  ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
  List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
  Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();
```

Full Stack Trace is as follow

```
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.(FileUploadBase.java:814)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:323)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:341)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
    at com.recruitment.joiningform.CandidateJoiningformDispatchAction.uploadPhoto(CandidateJoiningformDispatchAction.java:1404)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:270)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:187)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: The server side doesn't care how it gets there; you'd use the same mechanism as any other form with a file.

Comment: But the bean shows null value. And also I cannot parse inputstream to get the file. From direct file upload file can be got from the bean object. But it is not possible by this method. There are some methods to get value from these type of methods using apache FileUpload but it shows error.

Comment: "It shows error" really doesn't help much.

Comment: @Azhar please upload your complete back-end code and stack trace what error you are getting ?

Comment: I have edited the question